# Butterknife DI for local variable

Tags: android, butterknife

I started using Butterknife but now am facing one issue with my local variable declaration ie I forced to use Butterkinfe.findbyid(view,id). IS there any way to use annotation here

For Example:

```
private void setText(){

 TextView textView=Butterknife.findbyid(view,R.id.xyz);
}
```

am looking for @Bind(R.id.xyz) TextView textview;

Comment: why must the TextView be local scope?  Is there a reason it can't be class scope?

Comment: In many case I can see only local scope that is why am declaring the view element locally

Comment: @ripple182 because a good approach is to always keep the variable (method etc...) scope as narrow as possible, and expand it only if there is a good reason.

Answer (score 13):

The [Bind annotation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/javadoc/) only applies to fields -  if you're using a local variable, `ButterKnife.findById()` is the correct approach.